# Could sed ignore a part of the input file?

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following file example

```
some lines to parse
#CODE
some codes don't want to change
#ENDCODE
some lines to parse
```

Could sed ignore the part between #CODE and #ENDCODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the range operator.

```
sed '/^#CODE$/,/^#ENDCODE$/!s/foo/bar/'
```

will replace "foo" with "bar" only outside the code range.